# How to delete element on document by key in Mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongo document:

```
"parameters" : {
    "59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b" : {
        "Speed" : "900"
    },
    "59209f31470e6cb90e3c986b" : {
        "Weight" : [
            "1"
        ]
    }
},
```

I need to delete element from `parameters` by key `"59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b"`. How to do that?

I tried:

```
$new = array('$pull' => array("parameters" => $this->mongoDbID($id)));

$this->collection->update(array("parameters" => []), $new);
```

Also I tried:

```
$this->collection->update(array(), array('$pull'=>array('‌​parameters'=> $id)));
```

I tried also:

```
$this->collection->update(
            array(),
            array('$pull' => array('parameters' => $id, []))
        );
```

It gives me:

> localhost:27017: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value

**Full document:**

```
 > db.objects.find().pretty()
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5920b488470e6c910b3c986d"),
        "name" : "dadasd",
        "category_id" : "591efb0f470e6ccc143c9873",
        "prototype_id" : "591ed2f0470e6ccc143c986e",
        "parameters" : {
            "5920a907470e6cf80d3c986b" : {
                "adadad" : "dad"
            }
        },
        "parameters_type" : {
            "5920a907470e6cf80d3c986b" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "available" : "1"
    }
```

Comment: try to unset......

Comment: Can you share example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483897/mongodb-php-delete-element-from-array

Comment: I tried this, it does not work for me

Comment: kkk ... wait ...

Comment: $parameters->update(array('_id'=>$id),array('$pull'=>array('parameters'=>$key)));
ex: $key = "59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b"

Comment: I dont know `_id'=>$id`. It should find all rows

Comment: try ... it... .first..

Comment: I tried, it does not work: `$this->collection->update(array(), array('$pull'=>array('‌​parameters'=> $id)));`

Comment: It work, but this is $set: `$this->collection->update(array(), array('$set'=> array('‌​parameters'=> [])), array('multiple' => true));`

Comment: try This... $collection->update(
        array(
            'field' => array('$exists' => true),
        ),
        array(
            '$unset' => array(
                'field' => '',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'multiple' => true
        )
    );

Comment: . okk..... . !! :)

Comment: Do you mean this: ` $this->collection->update( array( 'parameters' => array('$exists' => true), ), array( '$unset' => array( 'parameters' => $id, ) ), array( 'multiple' => true ) );
`?

Comment: It works, but it deleted all `parameters`

Comment: ok okk.... then first one is fine ..

Comment: I can not find some information about that, how to delete

Comment: Read it .... https://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-blog-app-mongodb-php/

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php

Comment: I have collection inside

Comment: I tried also: `$this->collection->remove(array("parameters" => $id), array("justOne" => true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You're trying to do is `$unset` (docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/))

Now example:

```
$docId = $this->mongoDbID('5920b488470e6c910b3c986d');
$parameterId = '59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b';
$this->collection->update(
  ['_id' => $docId],
  ['$unset' => [
      'parameters.'.$parameterId => null, 
      'parameters_type.'.$parameterId => null
  ]]
);
```

or :

```
$parameterId = '59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b';
$this->collection->update(
  [],
  ['$unset' => [
      'parameters.'.$parameterId => null, 
      'parameters_type.'.$parameterId => null
  ]],
  ['multiple' => true]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution As Per Your Ans:**

```
$this->parametersCollection->update(array('_id'=>$id),array('$unset'=>array('parameters_Id' => $null)));
```

> Or

```
$this->parametersCollection->update(array('_id'=>$id),array('$unset'=>array('parameters_Id' => $null)),array('multiple' => true));
```

ex: $key = "59209f26470e6c8d0b3c986b"

**Some Reference Links For php-mongodb**

1.http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php

2.http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php

3.http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

4.http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php

5.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: It gives me: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array val

Comment: $this->collection->update(array(), array('$set'=> array('‌​parameters'=> Null)), array('multiple' => true));

Comment: It set null for all `parameters` not delete one element

Comment: May be: `$this->collection->update(array(), array('$set'=> array('‌​parameters.'.$id => Null)), array('multiple' => true));` ?

Comment: Nothing does now work (: Please see question again, keys is simple string values.

Comment: Lets got to chat

Comment: I added full document in question